# Highcharts 11 upgrade failed Angular App. No Appropriate loader handle the file type

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

Error in ./node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js 8:5207
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (8:5207)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

I have an Angular 10 app and importing highcharts into components using the command "`import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts'`".
I am trying to update from 8.2.2 to version 11.2.0 and getting the above error.

Comment: What version of highcharts-angular integration are you using? https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular?tab=readme-ov-file#general-prerequisites

Comment: I not using high chart-angular instead directly using higchart v11.2.0

Comment: So my suggestion is that you try the official `highcharts-angular` wrapper, it may solve your problem. 

Answer (score 1):

verify that you have that in provider table import :

```
import {HighchartsChartModule} from "highcharts-angular";
imports: [
//others modules ...
 HighchartsChartModule, 
]
```

and in ts file use that :

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
```

Comment: I found that issue occurring only on v11.2.0 not on 11.1.0